# ORA-00904: "FORMAT": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

I am trying to format a date:

```
FORMAT(table.TCKT.TCKT_ISS_DATE, 'YYYY') AS TICKETYEAR
```

but I am getting the following error:

ORA-00904: "FORMAT": invalid identifier

Right now the date show the complete timestamp. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem, or any other way to format the date to just show the four digit year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this function:

```
TO_CHAR(table.TCKT.TCKT_ISS_DATE, 'YYYY') AS TICKETYEAR
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`TO_CHAR`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) instead of `FORMAT` here, like this:

```
TO_CHAR(table.TCKT.TCKT_ISS_DATE, 'YYYY') AS TICKETYEAR
```

Oracle uses `TO_CHAR` for string casting, [you can see here for additional format options](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php).

Answer (score 0):

There's also the option of using `EXTRACT()` which is ANSI-standard and portable:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table.TCKT.TCKT_ISS_DATE) AS ticketyear
```